# sending get / put / post in swift

Tags: swift, xml, post, get, put

I can easily issue a GET request and it returns (as expected) JSON data that is decoded to myDataModel object:

```
class func getData(completionHandler: @escaping (myDataModel?, Error?) -> Void)
{
    let url = "https://example.com/api/someResource?ws_key=ABC...XYZ"
    if let myUrl = URL(string: url)
    {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: myUrl)
        {
            (data, response, err) in

            if let data = data
            {
                do
                {
                    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(myDataModel.self, from: data)
                    completionHandler(result, nil)
                }
                catch let JSONerr
                {
                    completionHandler(nil, JSONerr)
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

This work fine, so GET is no problem. (PS. the above has been simplified and modified.)

Likewise, I can issue a POST request and it returns (as expected) JSON data, when I use parameters like `key1=value1&key2=value2`.  (I read that the default POST `Content-Type` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.)

However, in another application I need to POST a piece of XML.  After many tries and getting many errors, the approach I'm using is to: Set the header `Content-Type` to `text/xml; charset=utf-8`;  Have no parameters and send the XML as the request body.  I use a refined method:

```
PostHTTP(url: "https://example.com/api/someResource?ws_key=ABC...XYZ",
  parameters: nil,
  headers: ["Content-Type": "text/xml; charset=utf-8", "Content-Length": "\(xml.count)"],
  body: "\(xml)")   {   (result) in ... }
```

(I image that you can determine what happens behind the scenes.)

**For the POST request, to send a piece of XML:**

Do I need to set the `Content-Length` or is this automatic?

Can I send parameters with the XML?

What headers (like `Content-Type`) do I require?

What structure (eg. `xml=<?xml`...) and encoding (eg. `addingPercentEncoding`) do I require?

Also I need to PUT data and I have similar method.  The response from my attempt has the error

> String could not be parsed as XML, XML length: 0

**For a PUT request:**

What headers (like `Content-Type`) do I require?

What structure (eg. `xml=<?xml`...) and encoding (eg. `addingPercentEncoding`) do I require?

Since I have tried many ways, an example of both PUT and POST would be ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send data of `XML` you can do this in both `PUT` and `POST`

It does not have to be determined `Content-Length`
But you must add `Content-Type`

```
 let req = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string:"myUrl")!)
            req.httpMethod = "POST"
            req.setValue("application/xml;charset=utf-8;", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            req.setValue("application/xml;", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
            var postBody = Data()
            if let anEncoding = ("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>").data(using: .utf8) {
                postBody.append(anEncoding)
            }
            if let anEncoding = "<Request>".data(using: .utf8) {
                postBody.append(anEncoding)
            }
            if let anEncoding = "<test>\(123)</test>".data(using: .utf8) {
                postBody.append(anEncoding)
            }

            if let anEncoding = "</Request>".data(using: .utf8) {
                postBody.append(anEncoding)
            }
            req.httpBody = postBody

            req.setValue("\(postBody.count)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: req as URLRequest) { (data, urlreq, error) in

            }
```

Comment: Like you said, I ensured I had those headers and removed the addPercent...
see raw output: https://ibb.co/kC0QTy

Comment: It is clear in the image that you experimented using a tool and not through the code, Can you attach a screenshot of how you put the Body

Comment: I have decided to not use any external helper libraries - everything is my own code via swift.
https://ibb.co/e5WcrJ is my main method for the PUT and https://ibb.co/ngXiWJ is my main method for the POST.  Each calls `object2psxml` (screen 1- https://ibb.co/he4ady and screen 2- https://ibb.co/gViOWJ) to create XML from my objects.  Then the POST request is done with (screen 1- https://ibb.co/iCMoyy and screen 2- https://ibb.co/gZasQd); the PUT is done with (screen 1- https://ibb.co/eBWGkd and screen 2- https://ibb.co/fS8Jyy).  Anything more needed?  What tool(s) do you think I'm using?

Comment: Is it possible to attach a screenshot of the your parameter
, Do you add this at first `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>`, Always make sure you are sending parameters as data not string , and `content-length` count data not string count

Comment: Not sure what you're referring to.  The methods PutHTTP & PostHTTP both have nil parameters, so I guess you mean the httpbody.  Method `object2psxml` converts an object (instance of myDataModel) into a XML string.  (Within the above methods it's converted to data - they have `.data(using: .utf8)`, so they should be encoded as you say.)  But I've eliminated the `Content-Length` header - should I use it again?  I notice that I'm doing string.count in both methods, but only with the parameters which are nil.  Are the code screen grabs easy to read?

Comment: I do not understand you, please explain what they are parameters in  `PutHTTP & PostHTTP`

Comment: It may be a bit confusing, because I have a parameter name in PutHTTP & PostHTTP called 'parameters'.  It is best to look at the screen grabs to know what I am doing